# How to inject service (AuthenticationStateProvider) in Blazor class

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm struggling to inject a service (AuthenticationStateProvider) in a class in Blazor server. If I do it in a razor component, it is pretty simple:

`@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider`

and then

```
private async Task LogUsername()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
       ClientMachineName = $"{user.Identity.Name}";
    }
    else
    {
       ClientMachineName = "Unknown";
    }
}
```

However I need to do this, i.e. retrieve the authenticated user machine name, in a class instead of a razor component.

I tried for instance:

```
[Inject]
AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; }

public async Task LogUsername()
{        
    var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    var user = authState.User;

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        ClientMachineName = $"{user.Identity.Name}";
    }
    else
    {
        ClientMachineName = "Unknown";
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the solution I had to this problem here:

[Accessinging an authenticated user outside of a view in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744356/accessinging-an-authenticated-user-outside-of-a-view-in-blazor/59753964#59753964)

This should solve your problem.

Edit: If you would like to get the information about the authentication state, what you should do is create a claim on the authentication state with the username or whatever detail you require in it, instead of creating a class and assigning the name to that. That way, in classes that need this information you can just inject a service class that gets all of the claims on the current authentication state. This really should all be done in a custom authentication state provider.

Example:

```
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    MyUser = //DB call to get user information
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new 
    Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, MyUser.Name) }, "Authenticated");
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    return new AuthenticationState(user);
}
```

Then in another service you would get the claims with the user information in it and inject that into any other service/class the information is needed.

```
public ApplicationUser(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
{
    _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
}

public async Task<string> GetLogin()
{
    var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    return authState.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
```

Comment: this might be it! I cannot comment in your other post (low reputation:) but can you pls let me know what is the syntax for this: "inject the AuthenticationStateProvider into your service class"

Comment: Sure thing! Basically it's the code I have in the link... In the class you are trying to use the provider in, you need to create a constructor for it that takes AuthenticationStateProvider as a parameter. You then assign that to the readonly _authenticationStateProvider in the class and use that to do your operations. Does this make sense? If not, let me know!

Comment: Edited answer...this should do it... I just implemented the same thing in my application.

Answer (score 10):

with Blazor server (.Net Core 3), this worked for me:

```
public class AuthTest
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

    public AuthTest(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }

    public async Task<IIdentity> GetIdentity()
    {
        var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        return user.Identity;
    }
}
```

You need to register this with the ASP.Net Core DI in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<AuthTest>();
```

And then inject it on your `.razor` page:

```
@page "/AuthTest"
@inject AuthTest authTest;
<button @onclick="@LogUsername">Write user info to console</button>

@code{
    private async Task LogUsername()
    {
        var identity= await authTest.IsAuthenticated();
        Console.WriteLine(identity.Name);
    }
```

You should see the logged-in username written to the ASP.Net output console.

Update
If you want to get the currently logged in user from within a separate class and you're not injecting that onto a blazor page, then follow the guidance [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state)

Comment: Thanks Stephen - but my problem is that I would like to consume this 'AuthTest' service from another class, and not from a .razor page (your last step). Essentially I would like to get the identity.Name output in a .cs file (my user service where I use this username to retrieve information about the user). Any idea how to do that? Thank you

Comment: @PeterPirc - oh I see, my bad.OK, can you describe how it doesn't work?

Comment: @StephenByrne thank you for pointing me in the right direction but whenever I do this my httpContext always returns null (I have registered the service). I am not sure what's going on... any advice? For clarification, I am using a server side application with windows authentication; I just want to access the claims made in it in my service classes (IE, the login/email of the authenticated user).

Comment: @PeterPirc - so just to clarify something, what's the entry point for this code, is it the blazor code section or is it a WebApi controller?

Comment: Hello @StephenByrne - thanks a lot for helping out with this, much appreciated. I need to play with this a little bit more; however I believe that the httpContextAccessor retrieves the server username and not the client username. I will investigate more and report back. Also it seems like the answer Dan provided below might be the solution to my issues.

Comment: You cannot use `IHttpContextAccessor` in Blazor - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0#blazor-and-shared-state

Comment: @AndrewL - yes it certainly seems like a bad idea from that linked article...honestly cannot recall if that was the guidance at the time. Anyways, thanks for pointing it out, I'll update this answer to reflect.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks again both @StephenByrne and @Dan - I'm almost there now with my requirements. This is my user service class and it works as expected:

```
public class AuthUser
{

    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

    public AuthUser(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        var username = _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;
        FetchMyUser(username.User.Identity.Name);
    }

    public User MyUser { get; set; }

    public void FetchMyUser(string machineName = "Unknown")
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(SettingsService.DBConnectionString2016))
        {
            MyUser = connection.QueryFirstOrDefault<User>($"SELECT FirstName FROM MyTable WHERE MachineName = '{machineName}' ;");
        }
    }
}
```

And then in Startup.cs I add this service as Scoped (this is important, as Dan pointed out below);

```
services.AddScoped<AuthUser>();
```

I can then use this service from a .razor component as follows:

```
@inject AuthUser authUser

Hello @authUser.MyUser.FirstName
```

The only remaining issue I have is that I don't know how to consume this service in another .cs class. I believe I should not simply create an object of that class (to which I would need to pass the authenticationStateProvider parameter) - that doesn't make much sense. Any idea how I could achive the same as I mentioned in the .razor file but in a .cs class instead ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use the `authenticationStateProvider` very much in code and would like to use `_authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;` like in this answer. If `.Result` is used minimally, is it an acceptable practice?

Answer (score 1):

if you in your startup.cs add some services

```
services.AddScoped<TokenProvider>();
services.AddTransient<TokenRefreshService>();
services.Add<GraphServiceService>();
```

you can in a razor page inject them by their type

```
@inject TokenProvider _token
@inject TokenRefreshService _tokenrefresh
@inject GraphServiceService _graphservice
```

These service classes, you inject them in throught the constructor

```
public GraphServiceClass(AuthenticationStateProvider _AuthenticationStateProvider, TokenProvider _token)
{
    AuthenticationStateProvider = _AuthenticationStateProvider;
    token = _token;
}
```

I recommend this: [ASP.NET Core Blazor dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1)